# SQL Contains: Query operators

Tags: sql, oracle, jpa

I got a query working from long ago, the query is build by JPA, but today threw an exception:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.HibernateJdbcException: JDBC exception on Hibernate data access: SQLException for SQL [n/a]; SQL state [99999]; error code [29902]; could not extract ResultSet; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not extract ResultSet at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:973)

Long story short, it gives **SQL state [99999]; error code [29902];** a parameter problem.

The query its build like this:

```
select * from mytable where CONTAINS(field1, 'BT');
```

[A little *google-fu* show me that **BT** its a query operator for *Contains*.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28304/cqoper.htm) This error can be reproduced searching by **NOT**, **DIFMERGE**, **ABOUT**, **AND**..

The question is, there is a way to escape the text so i can search by the word **BT** or his friends?

EDIT: i build the contains like this:

```
return builder.greaterThan(
            builder.function("CONTAINS", Integer.class, exp, builder.literal(((String) param.getValue()).toUpperCase())),
            0);
```

EDIT: I tried converting the text **BT** to unicode, but doesn't work either.

> select * from myTableWHERE CONTAINS(field1, UNISTR('\0042\0054')) > 0

Comment: why not use *where field1 like '%BT%'*? You can construct such queries with Hibernate (though you will have to append yourself the '%'s to the parameter value).

Comment: @JhonDonn I think i moved from like to contains beacause problems with text indexes, i dont remember well.